# Uploading multiple images to firebase collection and firebase using react native expo

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, javascript-framework

Am trying to uploading multiple images to firebase storage and firebase database collection using react native 'expo' but it's giving a hard time, i even tried using chatGpt but the code generated is confusing and somehow outdated so its not working[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aerxs.jpg)

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function for this. Here's:

```
import { ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage'
import { auth, storage } from '../../config/firebase'
export async function uploadImage(uri) {
try {
    const response = await fetch(uri)
    const blobFile = await response.blob()

    const image_name = 'image_name'
    const metadata = {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg',
        customMetadata: {
            from: auth?.currentUser?.uid
        }
    }

    const reference = ref(storage, image_name)
    const result = await uploadBytes(reference, blobFile, metadata)
    const url = await getDownloadURL(result.ref)

    return url
} catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(err)
}
}
```